# How to stop the user to enter the data in outside the fields in the J2ME application?

Tags: java, java-me

I have J2ME application, contains lot of forms and lists.

I have the following problem in that application.

Whenever I enter the details of the form and press down button, the cursor is coming to the space available in between the fields and footer of the form, After that if I press the middle button it is allowing the user to type data.

please help me,how to stop the user to enter data in outside of the fields ?

Answer (score 1):

U might have added some field inside it. j2me doesnt allows editing on the form . please provide the code so that we can help u

Comment: Hi Azhar, thanks for your reply.  Actually my form have some hidden fields and string items. Whenever the cusrsor focused on the hidden fields and string items, these are allowing the user to type some data. Please give some suggestion, how to rectify it?

Comment: try fieldname.setEditable(false);

Comment: thank you verymuch Azhar, I solved the issue, I used setFocusable(false) to the String Items and Hidden fields.